# Xamarin Connect to Mac Build Host using Keys

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way for connecting to mac buildhost using private / public key pairs?

Since login as user through ssh is not allowed in our company, I am searching for a workaround.

Comment: I used a Workaround. I asked the security team to disable the rule for the user-auth for a short moment. While disabled, I logged in once. Once the rule was reenabled it worked, since xamarin already generated the public / private keys.

Comment: I am however still looking for a real solution, since opening the user-auth for every new login is a lot of unneccessary work.